# Close Discord message on button click

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a select menu with a submit button. When submit is clicked I want to close the current message, submit the data and then open a new select menu but I am having trouble figuring out how to have the message close.

How can I have the current menu and button close when the submit button is clicked?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Any by "close" do you mean just delete? Have you tried just submitting the data, creating the new message with the new view and deleting the original message?

Comment: @ESloman Yes sorry. I just won't want to leave a bunch of messages open, I'd like to keep it clean. Make a selection, submit data, close message, open next message... repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn my comment into an answer; you can just delete the message on button press. For example, my `Cancel` buttons look a little like this:

```py
@discord.ui.button(label="Cancel", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, row=3, disabled=False, emoji="✖️")
async def cancel_callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.message.delete()
```

This is within a custom `View` class so might have to be adapted for your needs - but using the [`interaction.message`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Interaction.message) attribute to delete the message is the way to go.